# Chrome Extension: How to Import / Export bookmarks programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I made Chrome extension that automatically updates bookmarks url based on given regular expression and for this i needed to create my own bookmark manager.

I have managed to recreate most of original functionality with the help of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks , but the feature that i have not been able to recreate is Export and Import bookmarks.

The only related events mentioned in given docs are `onImportBegan`and `onImportEnded` which do not solve my problem, since what i need is to initiate Import/Export.

Keep in mind that i would know how to manually create my own Import/Export, but Chrome (if i am informed correctly) has a limit on how much times an extension can call `bookmarks.create` function per second, so this is out of the box.

Am i missing something or is Import/Export functionality simply not supported by google for chrome extensions, and if so what am i supposed to do then?

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `getTree()`? _"`chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function callback)`
Retrieves the entire Bookmarks hierarchy."_

Comment: Last time I've tried to create thousands of bookmarks in a loop there was no limit.

Comment: @wOxxOm it seems that you are correct, i have recently noticed that constants MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR and MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE have been deprecated since Chrome 38 as stated in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#property-MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR) so i guess one acceptable solution is for me to manually implement Export/Import which i am fine with.

Comment: @guest271314 So far i have assumed that tree returned is a deep copy of the bookmarks tree, but after further investigation it is highly likely that my assumption could be wrong. In case of a shallow copy manual implementation of Import/Export would actually be pretty easy! Thanks for suggestion, i will try it out!

Comment: @DaniloNovaković Bookmarks can definitely be exported. It depends on how you want to get and "export" the bookmarks.

Comment: @DaniloNovaković Were you able to learn how to export? I was actually looking for the same answer that you need. You might want to share your solution.